# NFS mount internal error

Tags: iptables, nfs, mount

I have a server that I use for NFS share. 4 servers use it without a problem.
I configured a new server and that can't mount. 
I get this error

```
   mount.nfs: internal error
```

In the logfile of the client:

```
   nfs: server 192.168.1.100 not responding, timed out
```

On the server I opened the ports I need, and in the log I can see this:

```
   rpc.mountd[20520]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.1.10:824 for /mnt/nfs/archive/server05 (/mnt/nfs/archive)
```

iptables rules on the nfs server:

```
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1:1024 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1:1024 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32803 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 32803 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32769 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 32769 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2020 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 2020 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.10/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 8125 -j ACCEPT
```

some more info

```
    [root@nfs_server]# rpcinfo -p
       program vers proto   port  service
        100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
        100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
        100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
        100024    1   udp    662  status
        100024    1   tcp    662  status
        100005    1   udp    892  mountd
        100005    1   tcp    892  mountd
        100005    2   udp    892  mountd
        100005    2   tcp    892  mountd
        100005    3   udp    892  mountd
        100005    3   tcp    892  mountd
        100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
        100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
        100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
        100227    2   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
        100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
        100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
        100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
        100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
        100227    2   udp   2049  nfs_acl
        100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
        100021    1   udp  32769  nlockmgr
        100021    3   udp  32769  nlockmgr
        100021    4   udp  32769  nlockmgr
        100021    1   tcp  32803  nlockmgr
        100021    3   tcp  32803  nlockmgr
        100021    4   tcp  32803  nlockmgr
```

hosts.allow

```
    [root@nfs_server]# cat /etc/hosts.allow
    portmap:ALL
    lockd:ALL
    mountd:ALL
    rquotad:ALL
    statd:ALL
```

**If I stop iptables it works.**

I have tried many things and searched for a long time. Please help...

Comment: `If I stop iptables it works.` Stopping it on the client? The server? Both?

Comment: Stopping it on the nfs server.

Comment: Also if I open all the ports for the client on the nfs server it works, so probably I'm missing a port but I don't know which.

Answer (score 0):

Per redhat.com - 9.7.3 Running NFS Behind a Firewall -

Procedure 9.1. Configure a firewall to allow NFS

Allow TCP and UDP port 2049 for NFS.
Allow TCP and UDP port 111 (rpcbind/sunrpc).
Allow the TCP and UDP port specified with MOUNTD_PORT="port"
Allow the TCP and UDP port specified with STATD_PORT="port"
Allow the TCP port specified with LOCKD_TCPPORT="port"
Allow the UDP port specified with LOCKD_UDPPORT="port"

Comment: As I said, I searched for a long time and tried everything. I have done that already

        RQUOTAD_PORT=875
        LOCKD_TCPPORT=32803
        LOCKD_UDPPORT=32769
        MOUNTD_PORT=892
        STATD_PORT=662
        STATD_OUTGOING_PORT=2020